# SQL trigger trouble with TRY--CATCH block for INSERT command

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

Ok, so I want to create a trigger that fires when someone tries to insert into the table "products" and checks for a valid foreign key. For right now (This is NOT the end design in the least, but I'm using it for testing), I want the trigger to check that the inserted line references a valid ID in the Manufacturer table, and if no such row exists in the Manufacturer table, insert one with the proper ID and some general information for the remaining fields. My current code is as follows:

```
create trigger checkman
on dbo.products
instead of insert
as
declare
@manid char(5),
@manName varchar(50),
@transactionName varchar(20) = 'transaction1'

Begin
select @manid=Man_ID from Inserted

begin try
    /*begin tran @transactionName*/
    Insert into Manufacturers (Man_ID, Man_Name, Man_Description) VALUES     @manid, 'Unknown Name', 'This is an unknown manufacturer');
    insert into dbo.products select * from inserted;
end try
begin catch
    /*rollback tran @transactionName;*/
    insert into dbo.products select * from inserted;
end catch



End
```

The problem is that whenever I run my insert with a Manufacturer ID that already exists, I get this error:

```
(0 row(s) affected)
Msg 3930, Level 16, State 1, Procedure checkman, Line 20
The current transaction cannot be committed and cannot support operations that write to        the log file. Roll back the transaction.
The statement has been terminated.
```

I get the same error when I put the "Insert into Manufacturers" line in the catch block, only this time it appears when I try to insert with an ID that doesn't yet exist.

Comment: I think you want a `before` trigger rather than an `instead of` trigger to add in the manufacturer id if it doesn't exist.

Comment: The insert to products should not be in the catch block. Move it outside the try catch altogether. If you want to have that error checked it should be in its own try catch.

Comment: The `inserted` virtual table can contain multiple rows. Your current code will only process the `Man_ID` from one row.

Answer (score 1):

Don't handle this in a try/catch block, it isn't necessary. Also you need to allow for the fact that `inserted` can contain multiple rows. You can do this using a NOT EXISTS query:

```
CREATE TRIGGER CheckMan
ON dbo.products
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
    INSERT Manufacturers (Man_ID, Man_Name, Man_Description)
    SELECT  DISTINCT Man_ID, 'Unknown Name', 'This is an unknown manufacturer'
    FROM    inserted i
    WHERE   NOT EXISTS
            (   SELECT  1
                FROM    Manufacturers m
                WHERE   m.Man_ID = i.Man_ID
            );

    INSERT  dbo.Products
    SELECT  *
    FROM    inserted;
```

**HOWEVER**, I don't advocate this approach, I think it would be much better to just rely on the referencial integrity provided by the foreign key itself, and if the Man_ID does not exist let the insert fail, and if necessary ensure all `Man_ID`s exist **before** even attempting to insert.

Answer (score 0):

I changed your trigger to following. In doing so, I made a few implicit assumptions. Assuming here that Products is a 3 column table (col1 & col2 being the other columns apart from Man_ID).

Hope this helps

```
alter
 trigger checkman
on dbo.products
instead of insert
as
declare
@manid char(5),
@col1 varchar(50),
@transactionName varchar(20) = 'transaction1',
@col2 Varchar(500) 
Begin
select @manid=Man_ID, @col1 = col1, @col2 = col2 from Inserted

IF (NOT EXISTS (SELECT Man_ID
      FROM Manufacturers Where Man_ID = @manid
      ))
   INSERT INTO ManuFacturers (Man_ID, Man_name, Man_Description) Values    (@manid, 'Unknown Name', 'This is an unknown manufacturer')

   INSERT INTO Products (Man_ID, col1, col2) values (@manid, @col1, @col2)

--begin try
--    /*begin tran @transactionName*/
--    Insert into Manufacturers (Man_ID, Man_Name, Man_Description) VALUES     (@manid, 'Unknown Name', 'This is an unknown manufacturer')
--    insert into dbo.products select * from inserted;
--end try
--begin catch
--    /*rollback tran @transactionName;*/
--    insert into dbo.products select * from inserted;
--end catch



End
```

Comment: You - as the OP, too - seem to assume that the trigger will always fire **once per row** - this is **NOT** the case, and if an `INSERT` operation inserts multiple rows, your trigger will be called **once** and the `Inserted` pseudo table will contain **multiple rows**! So which one of those potentially dozens, hundreds of rows are you selecting from here: `select @manid=Man_ID, @col1 = col1, @col2 = col2 from Inserted` ??? This trigger is doomed - you'll need to rewrite it to take into account that it will not be fired once per inserted row ....

Comment: @marc_s is right. that assumption of one row per insert is potential for trouble. Should've thought that through!